# twilio get dialed number

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have populated the following numbers from the database.

```
<Dial callerId="+266696687">
    <Number>8018xxxxxx</Number>
    <Number>8012xxxxxx</Number>
    <Number>8013xxxxxx</Number>
</Dial>
```

How to get the dialed number?

---

Okay, to clarify this question. [Updated 07/08/2012]

On the above details the 3 numbers will simultaneously ringings, right?

So, when one of them answers the call. How we can get the number?

Example, if **8018xxxxxx** answers the call, how I can get them? thru **$_REQUEST['Number']**? absolutely not **$_REQUEST['Dial']**.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the dialed number"? If you can explain what you are trying to do more broadly, that may help as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a URL on the  TWIML. At that URL you can then get the number and do whatever processing is required.

Please see the Twilio Docs at: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number

Comment: I already did the try and looks like this is the answer. +1 for you.